# Authoritative question about layover checkins

Tags: discussion, duplicates, canonical-questions

We frequently get nearly identical "Can I check additional luggage during a layover in X?" questions. A few random examples:

- [Is it possible to check in an additional piece of luggage in Singapore on a layover?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/56943/444)
- [Layover in CDG can I check my luggage through to DUB and go into Paris](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/18626/444)
- [Extra luggage drop-off in Dubai by Emirates during layover](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/53055/444)
- [Checking In Luggage During Intermediate Leg](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/46330/444)

I'm wondering if it would be reasonable to create a single, authoritative question/answer to address this question, rather than having all of these near-duplicates.

Now I'm not expert enough to know for sure whether a general answer is really reasonable, but I suspect that it may be, at least in a large number of cases. But are there enough general cases to justify a general authoritative answer, similar to the way we handled [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/34106/444)?

Comment: A great idea, please proceed with the question/answer pair.  I use MarkdownPad2 for those things, consider that tool for your composition

Comment: @GayotFow: Question [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/57014/444).

Answer (score 1):

There *might* be some scope to improve the answer but you have mentioned *Please edit this answer with impunity, if you can add any information or corrections* (and IMO making the answer a wiki one would be appropriate) but the Q/A pair have been well enough received so clearly to

> would it be reasonable to create a single, authoritative question/answer to address this question, rather than having all of these near-duplicates?

the answer would be YES!

to:

> But are there enough general cases to justify a general authoritative answer?

the answer is more a matter of opinion, where my opinion is also Yes! (though that is partly because I have a low threshold for the number required in a case such as this).